# Using SmartSheet API for "Smarter" email notifications

Tags: smartsheet-api

Currently in SmartSheet, users are able to assign email notifications to users, which are triggered when "Anything Changes" or a pre-specified column changes in a sheet.

While this is useful, there is a common business case where a sheet administrator needs to notify users based on the contents of a cell. For example, if the drop down option in Column A is set to Option A, User A gets notified, or if set to Option B, User B gets notified, etc.

Is this sort of conditional notification logic possible in the SmartSheet API v2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Smartsheet API doesn't currently support creating or managing alerts (i.e., notifications and reminders). So, to achieve the type of scenario you've described, you'd need to create an integration that:

- is able to know when the specified changes occur in the Sheet (ex: Column A is set to Option A for any row)
- contains the logic to determine which user(s) to email (ex: if Column A is set to Option A for any row, then email User A)
- sends the email(s)

At a high level, you have a couple of different options for accomplishing what I've outlined above:

1. Poll Smartsheet periodically (ex: hourly) to determine if the Sheet has changed ([Get Sheet Version](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet-version)) and if it has changed, evaluate sheet data ([Get Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet)); if data meets your criteria for sending email(s), then send email(s).
2. Alternatively, you could use "Smartsheet Webhooks" such that your integration will be notified when changes occur in the Sheet, then react to such notifications by subsequently using the API to evaluate sheet data ([Get Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) or [Get Row](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-row)); if data meets your criteria for sending email(s), then send email(s).  Smartsheet Webhooks are currently in [Private Beta](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/smartsheet-webhooks-private-beta-faqs) -- if you'd like to be considered for the private beta, you can apply by completing this [web form](https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form?EQBCT=ec72cd56dbfd4625bcf4599f989002de).

Comment: To add to Kim's comment, conditional notifications feature is on the roadmap for this year.  No firm target date yet, but it's being worked on.  Thanks for your patience.